# What’s the nuance between stop and put a stop to?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Consider the following two sentences:
(1) We should stop this project.
(2) We should put a stop to this project.

Is there any difference? Do those 2 sentences imply different things? From what I understood, you can stop something habitual like stop eating chocolate, but you can only put a stop to something that’s been going for a while like a war, a talk, or someone’s behavior. I can kinda feel it if something doesn’t sound right but am not quite sure if my intuition is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To 'stop' something is simply to end its further progress or motion. It can be used formally or informally.

To 'put a stop to' something is to emphatically stop it. Some, but not all, dictionaries say that it is used about stopping a bad or unwanted thing.

*Mother: our son Jack is drunk and he's going to drive your car! Father: I'll put a stop to that!*

*My neighbour started playing heavy metal on his boom box and put a stop to my afternoon nap.*

*I used to enjoy playing soccer on Saturdays, but a broken leg put a stop to it.*

Comment: You can _stop_ doing something yourself (_I stopped reading and looked up_), but you can only _put a stop to_ what someone else is doing.

Comment: @KateBunting - or someone else or something can put a stop to something you are doing, or a plan you have. 'Put the ky-bosk' on it as Dickens made a street lad say.